# How to determine the visibility li's in a scrollable ul

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<ul>` of more than 20 `<li>`'s. The max-height of `<ul>` is fixed therefore `<ul>` is scrollable and only 5 `<li>`'s are appearing at a time others are hiding either upside or downside. Each `<li>`'s having a index like first `<li>` has index of `0`, second `<li>` has `1` and so on.....

I want to know is there any way to know the index of `<li>`'s which are appearing at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the elements `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` properties, and if your `<li>` elements have fixed heights, you could calculate which are visible.

```
scrollTop / liHeight === numberOfOverTheFold
```

and

```
(scrollHeight - scrollTop) / liHeigth === numberOfVisible
```